# Handling async requests using multiple APIs - Python Flask Redis

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, redis

I'm working on an application that will have to consult multiple APIs for information and after processing the data, will output the answer to a client. The client uses a browser to connect to a web server to forward the request, afterwards, the web server will look for the information needed from the multiple APIs and after joining the responses from those APIs will then give an answer to the client.

The web server was built using Flask and a module that extracts the needed information for each API was also implemented (Python). Since the consulting process for each API takes time, I would like to give the web server a timeout for responding, therefore, after the requests are sent only those that are below the time buffer will be used.

**My proposed solution:**
Use a Redis Queue and an RQ worker to enqueue the requests for each API and store the responses on the Queue then wait for the timeout and collect the responses that were able to respond in the allowed time. Afterwards, process the information and give the response to the user.

The flask web server is setup something like this:

```
@app.route('/result',methods=["POST"])
def show_result():

inputText = request.form["question"]

tweetModule = Twitter()
tweeterResponse = tweetModule.ask(params=inputText)

redditObject = RedditModule()
redditResponse = redditObject.ask(params=inputText)    

edmunds = Edmunds()
edmundsJson = edmunds.ask(params=inputText)

# More APIs could be consulted here

# Send each request async and the synchronize the responses from the queue

template = env.get_template('templates/result.html')
return render_template(template,resp=resp)
```

The worker:

```
conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

And lets assume each Module handles its own queueing process.

I can see some problems ahead:

- What happens to the information stored on the queue that did not make it to the timeout?
- How can I make Flask wait and then extract the responses from the Queue?
- Is it possible that information could get mixed if two clients ask in the same time-frame?
- Is there a better way to handle the async requests and then synchronize the response?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

#### In such cases I prefer a combination of `HTTPX` and `flask[async]`

##### First - HTTPX

`HTTPX` offers a standard synchronous API by default, but also gives you the option of an `async` client if you need it.

`Async` is a concurrency model that is far more efficient than `multi-threading`, and can provide significant performance benefits and enable the use of long-lived network connections such as `WebSockets`.

If you're working with an async web framework then you'll also want to use an `async` client for sending outgoing HTTP `requests`.

```py
>>> async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
...     r = await client.get('https://www.example.com/')
...
>>> r
<Response [200 OK]>
```

##### Second - Using async and await in a `flask`

Routes, error handlers, before request, after request, and teardown functions can all be coroutine functions if Flask is installed with the `async` extra (`pip install flask[async]`). It requires Python 3.7+ where `contextvars.ContextVar` is available. This allows views to be defined with `async def` and use `await`.

For example, you should do something like this:

```py
import asyncio
import httpx
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/async', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
async def async_form():

    if request.method == 'POST':

        ...

        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            tweeterResponse, redditResponse, edmundsJson = await asyncio.gather(
                client.get(f'https://api.tweeter....../id?id={request.form["tweeter_id"]}', timeout=None),
                client.get(f'https://api.redditResponse.....?key={APIKEY}&reddit={request.form["reddit_id"]}'),
                client.post(f'https://api.edmundsJson.......', data=inputText)
            )

        ...

        resp = {
            "tweeter_response" : tweeterResponse,
            "reddit_response": redditResponse,
            "edmunds_json" : edmundsJson
        }



    template = env.get_template('templates/result.html')
    return render_template(template, resp=resp)
```